# How to annotate the data points with the index or column value in the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, label, annotate

I draw a normal distribution plot based on the dataframe, then I want to annotate some data points in the plot as the index or column value of that data points. For example, here we have a dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'col2': [3, 7, 9]})`

Then I draw a normal distribution plot using the values in 'col2'.

Now, I want to annotate or label some data points with the values in 'col1'.
For example, I want to show the 'col1' value (or text) which is 'B' on the data point '7' in the normal distribution plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Matplotlib's built-in [annotate](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) feature:

```py
####################### Just creating a mock dataframe #############################
import random                                                                     ##
import string                                                                     ##
import pandas as pd                                                               ##
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                   ##
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)                                          ##
                                                                                  ##
col1 = [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(500)]                ##
col2 = [random.choice(range(0,25)) for _ in range(500)]                           ##
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': col1, 'col2': col2})                                   ## 
####################################################################################


string = 'A'                                           # The string you want to find
index = df[df.col1.eq(string)].index                   # The index(es) at which that string is in col1
# index = df[df.col1.str.contains(string)].index       # If you are looking for a word or phrase in a string try this
y, x, _ = plt.hist(df.col2)                            # Plot the histogram and grab the x and y values 
plt.ylim(0, y.max()+10)                                # Set the ylim to the max y value plus some number
for pos in index:                                      # Annotate what you want (we'll just do the "string" value) at the...
    plt.annotate(string, (df['col2'][pos],y.max()+5), fontsize = 20)          #... corresponding value in col2 at that index
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think it is something similar that I was trying to do. I have an additional question: what if the dataframe has 1,000 number of rows, so I need to find a specific row with a specific text? Then, annotate the text from 'col1' on that data points? Assuming that I don't know the exact location of the row that I want to use. 
Also Do I need to specify the 'y' location for the text?

Comment: @Sol , check the edit, this may be more what you want. It finds the index(es) of the string (or word or phrase in the string if you use the commented out code) in `col1` then finds the corresponding value in `col2` and annotates that string at that value. Yes, you have to set the y value, but I added some code to automatically set it at some point above ymax.